# Undefined if constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr

This little piece of code drives me a bit crazy:

```
struct my_struct
{
private:
    static constexpr const char* some_string() noexcept;
public:
    my_struct() = default;
private:
    std::string _my_string{some_string()};
}

//in cpp
constexpr const char* my_struct::some_string() noexcept
{
    return "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,"
           "sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et"
           " dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.";
}
```

My compiler, `g++ (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2`, is complaining that `some_string` is undefined! Removing the `constexpr`-keyword solved the problem, but still whats the reason for this?

Is it some C++ rule I simply have missed *or* is it a compiler bug *or* neither of those options?

Comment: The definition is in the C++ file, right?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes.

Comment: It's a duplicate then :-)

Comment: missing `;` perhaps after the `struct` declaration? I can compile your code with no problems on gcc4.9.2 macports. http://ideone.com/qGbWXY

Comment: @dasblinkenlight How so? the class only provides a declaration, or so it seems to me

Comment: @Golazo This works for all functions except `constexpr`. Their definitions must be in the header in order to be useable in other translation units.